# Understanding how AndroidStudio generated code restores a PlaceholderFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I created a test application using AndroidStudio, selecting an activity with a fragment. What I do not understand is how the PlaceholderFragment is restored when savedInstanceState is not null, taking into account that setContentView is called **after** super.onCreate().

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello the savedInstanceState is only not null when you rotated the device. When the activity recreate it should load from savedInstanceState. by the way the code you are talking about is part of android activity not android studio. Thank you.

Comment: I said "AndroidStudio generated code" meaning "code generated by AndroidStudio"

Comment: Yes I understand your point. but It is feature of android studios to create the Blank activity with fragment, the same code you can do it your self. now let me know what exactly your problem is ?

Comment: "When the activity recreate it should load from savedInstanceState", do you mean that the Activity should recreate the fragment using savedInstanceState? Please, clarify.

Comment: Yes activity also recreate the fragment

Comment: If you does not want to recreate the activity or fragment when screen rotated, you can also set the flag in android manifest .xml that will never recrete the activity when screen rotated thank you